# Company address book with Exchange integration

Tags: contact-manager, microsoft-exchange

I am searching a software to have a single data-source for company contact cards. In the company there are different branches, the main one has an Exchange Server but not all employees have an Exchange account, some have only IMAP on a different Domain.
Requirements:

- not only Exchange users have Access to this database, also other
  users (e.g. via CardDAV and an Outlook add-in?)
- Possibility to automatically synchronize new and changed contacts on mobile devices (Android, iOS, Win Phone) without third party apps like it works with Exchange contacts
- Some users have the privileges to add/Change the contact Details

I already tried public folders on the Exchange Server but it is not very comfortable for the user to find them in Outlook and there is no possibility to automatically synchronize them. Also not-Exchange users have no access to this contacts.